# I get the error "Coord Object does not support indexing" while trying to store data into multiple rows using flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I get the error

> Coord Object does not support indexing

while trying to store data into multiple rows using flask `sqlalchemy`.
This is my code:

```
class create_view(BaseView):
  # @expose('/')
  @expose('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
  def create(self):
    #  id_generator()
    # 'G5G74W'
    #  id_generator(3, "6793YUIO")
    # 'Y3U'

    Coord = Coordinate(From = request.form.get("from[]"),
                    lat = request.form.get("lat[]"),
                    lng = request.form.get("lng[]"),
                    to = request.form.get("to[]"),
                    bearing = request.form.get("bearing[]"),
                    distance = request.form.get("distance[]"),
                    land_id = id_generator())

    for j in range(len(Coord.lat)):
        print(Coord,file=sys.stderr)

        db.session.add(Coord[j])
        db.session.commit()

    return self.render('admin/create.html')
```

Does anybody know a solution of this problem?

Comment: Is it a typo in Form?

Comment: it is From,its a column name in the database,moreover if i remove the [j] from coord[j] it gives me an error Coord object is not iterable.Any Help